# Azure B2C Custom policy with domain hint for Google Idp fails on redirect

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom policy for SignIn SignUp in Azure B2C which uses a domain hint so that users can authenticate using Google.com.
After the user has authenticated in Google, he gets send back to the redirect_uri which is specified in the URL, but the user gets thrown back to the B2C Sign In page.
I can see in the Browser network there is a red line about a file logo.svg with status cancelled.
Wonder what happened here??

One test I did was this:
I ran my Blazor app from Visual Studio and when the B2C SignIn page shows up, I copy the generated Url and append the domain hint to it and run the Url and this works.

Obviously I cannot use this method. Anyone had this issue?